# How to load a static file from within a controller action with a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple versions of a document:

```
about_version1.html
about_version2.html
about_version3.html
```

In my controller I want to render the text from either version 1,2 or 3.

I want to also use a layout.

How can I load the contents file with a layout?  Is there built-in way in rails to read from a static asset like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Rails will use `/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as the default layout for all templates. To use a different layout, create a file in `/views/layouts` called `about.html.erb` and put `<%= yield %>` where you want to insert your template.

Then assuming you have all three template files under `/views/static`, do something like this:

```
## static_controller.rb
    def about
      version = params[:version]
      render "static/about_version#{version}.html.erb", layout: "about"
    end
```

Your will need to supply the param `:version` when you call `#about` of course.